# overriding default quota on a new GCP project created by Terraform module

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

i'm creating a new project and gke cluster however i'm hitting error below saying i need increase quota , all my tries failed due to these errors of google cloud (which make it obvious why google cloud is behind in market share in cloud market)

I have tried to request/increase/override in three ways

1. terraform module and getting error as follows:
   module i used: https://github.com/laithrafid/infra-api/tree/main/terraform/googlecloud/modules/gke_create

tfvar  has below

```
consumer_quotas = [
{
service = "compute.googleapis.com"
metric = "compute.googleapis.com/regional_in_use_addresses"
limit = "%2F100s%2Fproject"
value = "18"
}
]
```

```
Error: Error creating ConsumerQuotaOverride: googleapi: got HTTP response code 404 with body: <!DOCTYPE html>
│ <html lang=en>
│   <meta charset=utf-8>
│   <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
│   <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
│   <style>
│     *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
│   </style>
│   <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
│   <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
│   <p>The requested URL <code>/v1beta1/projects/kubernetes-cluster-2eaa/services/compute.googleapis.com/consumerQuotaMetrics/compute.googleapis.com/regional_in_use_addresses/limits/%2F100s%2Fproject/consumerOverrides/?alt=json&amp;force=true</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
│
│
│   with module.quota_project_factory.google_service_usage_consumer_quota_override.override["compute.googleapis.com-compute.googleapis.com/regional_in_use_addresses"],
│   on .terraform/modules/quota_project_factory/modules/quota_manager/main.tf line 21, in resource "google_service_usage_consumer_quota_override" "override":
│   21: resource "google_service_usage_consumer_quota_override" "override" {
```

2. gcloud cli and getting error as follows

```
gcloud alpha services quota update     --service=compute.googleapis.com    --consumer=projects/kubernetes-cluster-2eaa --metric=compute.googleapis.com/regional_in_use_addresses --unit=IN-USE-ADDRESSES-per-project-region   --value=20
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.services.quota.update) INVALID_ARGUMENT: quota unit must start with '1/'.
Help Token: Ae-hA1PFa9PldCcDf2KjLKhtp18iSaIugq4KS5JWIaaEvgsvaElMS-9Y4ln-TyZQp4h3bSzVG4HsfDJReGfcIHOBKOReCdPGDEd5NDfNieNfOvzx
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:
  - subject: '908015'
    type: googleapis.com
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: serviceusage.googleapis.com
  reason: SU_INVALID_UNIT
```

Error:

3. from UI console i added a request and nothing happened by google cloud team

Comment: Did you have activated the Compute Engine API before setting the quotas?

Comment: yes , part of projects api